# Change size of brush in a menustrip to draw different sizes in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, colors, drawing, menustrip

Okay, I am currently have an app where I can draw on it. I use radio buttons to select the color and drawing size of the "Pen" for the drawing. I would like to get rid of these radio buttons and use a MenuStrip on a MDI form to affect the color and size of the pen on a new child form within the MDI form.

Currently, this is what I have for the form that I can draw on that includes the radio buttons.

```
Public Class Form1


Private shouldPaint As Boolean = False
Dim paintColor As Color

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.MdiParent = ParentMdiForm

    'Color Radio Buttons
    Me.redRadio.Tag = Color.Red
    Me.blueRadio.Tag = Color.Blue
    Me.greenRadio.Tag = Color.Green
    Me.blackRadio.Tag = Color.Black

    Me.blackRadio.Checked = True

    'Size Radio Buttons
    Me.smallRadio.Checked = True
End Sub

'Draw while mouse button is pressed
Private Sub Painter_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    shouldPaint = True
End Sub

'Stop drawing when mouse button is not pressed
Private Sub Painter_MouseUp(Sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
    shouldPaint = False
End Sub

'Change the size of the pen
Private Sub Painter_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    If (shouldPaint) Then
        If smallRadio.Checked = True Then

            Using g As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
                g.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(paintColor), e.X, e.Y, 4, 4)
            End Using
        ElseIf mediumRadio.Checked = True Then
            Using g As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
                g.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(paintColor), e.X, e.Y, 8, 8)
            End Using
        ElseIf largeRadio.Checked = True Then
            Using g As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
                g.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(paintColor), e.X, e.Y, 12, 12)
            End Using
        End If

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles redRadio.CheckedChanged, blueRadio.CheckedChanged, greenRadio.CheckedChanged, blackRadio.CheckedChanged
    If CType(sender, RadioButton).Checked = True Then
        paintColor = CType(CType(sender, RadioButton).Tag, Color)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SizeRadioButton_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles smallRadio.CheckedChanged, mediumRadio.CheckedChanged, largeRadio.CheckedChanged
    If CType(sender, RadioButton).Checked = True Then

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

My question is, how do I use the menustrip to select the  size for my drawings? I figured out how to do it with the color but I cannot figure out the size. I am just not understanding how to code this.

Comment: *I figured out how to do it with the color but I cannot figure out the size.* What's the problem? Color is a type and Size is also the same, do what you have done for Color for Size too.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I tried just doing what I did for color and it does not work. I tried copy/pasting the 

Using g as Graphics = CreateGraphics() 

code I used above, but that does not work either. The MDI form code does not recognize the e.X and e.Y

Comment: *It doesn't work* is not a suitable problem description. It doesn't help us to help you. You need to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and let us know what the problem is, what's expected result and what the result or exception which you receive.

Comment: By the way, `Using g As Graphics = CreateGraphics()` is not the correct way of doing this. Just minimize the windows and restore it again to see the result. You should handle `Paint` event and use `e.Graphics` instead and draw the model there. In other events like `MouseMove` you should update model and call `Me.Invalidate` to force the `Form` redraw itself.